# MySQL Set column if other colum equals

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns

| Name | Setting | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | setting1 | option1 |
| **user1** | **setting2** | **option2** |
| user1 | setting3 | option1 |
| user1 | setting4 | option2 |
| user2 | setting1 | option1 |
| **user2** | **setting2** | **option2** |
| user2 | setting3 | option1 |
| user2 | setting4 | option2 |

How would I replace the **variable** to **option3** for each user only in the **setting2** row for that user? I can't do a simple find and replace because other rows, such as setting3, have identical values. These are short string values.

Comment: Can you share the update statement you tried so far to make it more clear?

Comment: what is the issue with update statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why a simple update cannot cover your requirement:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET Variable = 'option3'
WHERE Setting = 'setting2' AND Variable <> 'option3';
```